# digiKam installation problems on 16.04

Tags: software-installation, digikam

I have upgraded to 16.04 LTS from 14.04 as advised by Updater on 28 July 2016

The problem is:

The software, DigiKam did not install. It is not installed from Ubuntu Software also.

I have tried with using the Terminal with the following commands:348196

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install digikam
348196
blackie@BLACKIE-ITX001:~$ sudo apt-get install digikam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 digikam : Depends: digikam-data (= 4:4.12.0-0ubuntu7) but 4:4.14.0-trusty~ppa1kde414 is to be installed348196
           Recommends: kipi-plugins but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Querry:

How do I rectify this?

Comment: try with sudo apt-get install digikam digikam-data

Comment: Thanks for advice, but still failed to load but did mention kipi-plugins

Comment: Thank you Dumindu Mahawela for your advice.  Since then I installed ppa's relevent to digiKam that 16.04 had inhibited, RESULT digiKam and related applications now load.